# JavaScript calling a server-side calculation?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dom

** edited post - initial question essentially meant: **

I am trying to learn how to add a server-side calculation to my JavaScript.

To call the server-side calculation, I presume I need to use AJAX technology. But I am still unsure what form of data exchange I should expect for the return values?

** addition a few months later: **

The answer to this is: to webpages/routes are needed. One (call it "a") to interact with the user, the other one (call it "b") to perform the calculation. a calls b via an ajax request (XmlHttpRequest). b performs calculation and outputs a JSON object. a reads the JSON object and updates its DOM accordingly to output results.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to echo only the result of the calculation in PHP and let the JavaScript handle updating the HTML. This way you wouldn't need to replace the entire tag, but merely insert a new into the DOM or update an existing tag based upon the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pseudo code example handling both update and insert without reloading the entire thing.

```js
var number1 = document.getElementById('number1');
var number2 = document.getElementById('number2');
var modifiedExample = document.getElementById('modifiedExample');
var insertedExample = document.getElementById('insertedExample');
var ajaxHandle;

function something() {
  //I use timeout instead of AJAX, since i dont actually have a server to poll but it should be pretty interchangeable
  clearTimeout(ajaxHandle);
  var n1 = parseInt(number1.value, 10);
  var n2 = parseInt(number2.value, 10);
  ajaxHandle = setTimeout(function() {
    modifiedExample.value = n1 + n2;
    insertedExample.appendChild(document.createElement("li")).innerHTML = n1 + n2;
  }, 100 + 500 * Math.random());
}
```

```html
<form>
  Number 1: <input type="number" value="0" id="number1" onchange="something()" /><br/>
  Number 2: <input type="number" value="0" id="number2" onchange="something()" /><br/>
  Result: <input type="number" value="0" id="modifiedExample" readonly/>
</form>

<ul id="insertedExample">
  <li>Results are inserted here</li>
</ul>
```